# How to add the second z-axis in Graphics3D

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, overlay

In 2D plot, to add the second y-axis, the `Overlay` function is useful.
But I want to see the second z-axis in the Graphics3D.
Here is my code.

```
list1={{-0.8,0.},{-0.76,0.},{-0.72,0.},{-0.68,0.},{-0.64,0.},{-0.6,0.},{-0.56,0.},{-0.52,0.},{-0.48,0.},{-0.44,0.},{-0.4,0.},{-0.36,0.0001224},{-0.32,0.000548822},{-0.28,0.00519339},{-0.24,0.0136416},{-0.2,0.0241745},{-0.16,0.0454922},{-0.12,0.0814358},{-0.08,0.138059},{-0.04,0.186479},{0.,0.185257},{0.04,0.32583},{0.08,0.337788},{0.12,0.328776},{0.16,0.31703},{0.2,0.301829},{0.24,0.287121},{0.28,0.272735},{0.32,0.256914},{0.36,0.246121},{0.4,0.235349},{0.44,0.225455},{0.48,0.217635},{0.52,0.209689},{0.56,0.200621},{0.6,0.191258},{0.64,0.180928},{0.68,0.171638},{0.72,0.162067},{0.76,0.152626},{0.8,0.143067},{0.84,0.133765},{0.88,0.124707},{0.92,0.115423},{0.96,0.106569},{1.,0.0975273},{1.04,0.0874979},{1.08,0.0783145},{1.12,0.0690845},{1.16,0.0587479},{1.2,0.048408}};

list2={{-0.36,0.000426189},{-0.32,0.0014508},{-0.28,0.00294391},{-0.24,0.00488642},{-0.2,0.00631365},{-0.16,0.00709797},{-0.12,0.00795426},{-0.08,0.00909467},{-0.04,0.0101843},{0.,0.0121543},{0.04,0.0114111},{0.08,0.0110605},{0.12,0.0110529},{0.16,0.0112938},{0.2,0.0118095},{0.24,0.0129109},{0.28,0.0143636},{0.32,0.0163999},{0.36,0.0180335},{0.4,0.0206114},{0.44,0.0233723},{0.48,0.0266779},{0.52,0.0297078},{0.56,0.0322112},{0.6,0.0342747},{0.64,0.0357367},{0.68,0.0369895},{0.72,0.0378629},{0.76,0.0384923},{0.8,0.0386849},{0.84,0.0393198},{0.88,0.0400586},{0.92,0.040036},{0.96,0.0402633},{1.,0.0386925},{1.04,0.0361578},{1.08,0.0353478},{1.12,0.0344009},{1.16,0.0265764},{1.2,0.0232176}};

list3={{-0.8,0.},{-0.76,0.},{-0.72,0.},{-0.68,0.},{-0.64,0.},{-0.6,0.},{-0.56,0.},{-0.52,0.},{-0.48,0.},{-0.44,0.},{-0.4,0.},{-0.36,0.},{-0.32,0.},{-0.28,0.},{-0.24,0.000165496},{-0.2,0.00936814},{-0.16,0.0344037},{-0.12,0.0696774},{-0.08,0.121921},{-0.04,0.176766},{0.,0.216207},{0.04,0.305647},{0.08,0.332236},{0.12,0.328652},{0.16,0.316147},{0.2,0.301287},{0.24,0.286369},{0.28,0.274121},{0.32,0.267855},{0.36,0.26002},{0.4,0.251559},{0.44,0.242372},{0.48,0.232006},{0.52,0.224579},{0.56,0.215367},{0.6,0.210513},{0.64,0.204766},{0.68,0.197979},{0.72,0.191429},{0.76,0.184943},{0.8,0.17674},{0.84,0.167772},{0.88,0.159828},{0.92,0.151023},{0.96,0.14146},{1.,0.13105},{1.04,0.120954},{1.08,0.107326},{1.12,0.0966263},{1.16,0.0826209},{1.2,0.0688753}};

list4={{-0.24,0.00056432},{-0.2,0.00202481},{-0.16,0.00372379},{-0.12,0.00558917},{-0.08,0.00739978},{-0.04,0.00892806},{0.,0.011412},{0.04,0.0130475},{0.08,0.0148732},{0.12,0.0161947},{0.16,0.0172134},{0.2,0.0181374},{0.24,0.0194533},{0.28,0.0213164},{0.32,0.0235593},{0.36,0.026054},{0.4,0.0286032},{0.44,0.0309444},{0.48,0.0326746},{0.52,0.0356887},{0.56,0.0382414},{0.6,0.0416508},{0.64,0.045248},{0.68,0.0482828},{0.72,0.0507246},{0.76,0.0520799},{0.8,0.052563},{0.84,0.0519158},{0.88,0.0504791},{0.92,0.049353},{0.96,0.0469096},{1.,0.0448837},{1.04,0.0450835},{1.08,0.0437154},{1.12,0.0386753},{1.16,0.0329864},{1.2,0.0342237}};

option1[col_] := {Joined -> True,
   ImagePadding -> 60,
   ImageSize -> 600,
   PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 1.5}, {0.0, 0.5}},
   PlotStyle -> {{col, Opacity[0.3], Thick, Dashed}, None},
   Frame -> {True, True, True, False},
   FrameTicks -> {None, None, None, None},
   FrameLabel -> {"x", "eff", None, None},
   FrameStyle -> {
     Directive[Black, 18, Bold, Thick, FontFamily -> "Times"],
     Directive[Black, 18, Bold, Thick, FontFamily -> "Times"],
     Directive[Black, 18, Bold, Thick, FontFamily -> "Times"], None}};

option2[col_] := {Joined -> True,
   ImagePadding -> 60,
   ImageSize -> 600,
   Axes -> None,
   PlotRange -> {{-0.5, 1.5}, {0.0, 0.05}},
   PlotStyle -> {{col, Opacity[0.9], Thick}, None},
   Frame -> {False, False, False, True},
   FrameTicks -> All,
   FrameLabel -> {None, None, None, "rms"},
   FrameStyle -> {None, None, None, 
     Directive[Black, 18, Bold, Thick, FontFamily -> "Times"]}};

ploteff1 = ListPlot[list1, option1[Red]];
plotrms1 = ListPlot[list2, option2[Red]];
Overlay[{ploteff1, plotrms1}]
```

1st overlayed 2d plot
[image: the first overlayed 2d plot]

```
ploteff2 = ListPlot[list3, option1[Darker[Green]]];
plotrms2 = ListPlot[list4, option2[Darker[Green]]];
Overlay[{ploteff2, plotrms2}]
```

2nd overlayed 2d plot
[image: the second overlayed 2d plot]

```
col[opa_] := {Opacity[opa, Red], Opacity[opa, Darker[Green]]}
layer[list_, i_] := list /. {x_, z_} :> {x, i, z}
g1 = (5 #) &;

Graphics3D[
 {{Thick, Dashed, col[0.3][[1]], Line[layer[list1, 1]]},
  {Thick, Dashed, col[0.3][[2]], Line[layer[list3, 2]]},
  {Thick, col[0.9][[1]], Line[MapAt[g1, layer[list2, 1], {;; , 3}]]},
  {Thick, col[0.9][[2]], Line[MapAt[g1, layer[list4, 2], {;; , 3}]]}

  },
 Axes -> True,
 (*FaceGrids\[Rule]All,*)
 Ticks -> {Range[-0.5, 1.5, 0.5], {1, 2}, Range[0.0, 0.5, 0.1]},
 TicksStyle -> 
  Directive[Black, FontFamily -> "Times", Bold, 16] {1, 1, 1},
 BoxRatios -> {1.1, 1, 0.5},
 ImageSize -> 700
 ]
```

[image: joined 2d plots in 3d]

In this situation, I want to make it 3D using `Graphics3D` with the second z-axis like second y-axis in 2D plot. I tried it but I have no idea.
How can I add not only basic x,y,z axis but also the additional axes?

[image]

Comment: @corey979 Sorry, I changed the form.

Comment: Try not to include so much superfluous style options in the question, it distracts from the main point, which is "How to label multiple edges in a 3D plot", which I don't see an easy answer for.

Comment: For the 2D plot you made, you don't have to resort to `Overlay` (which I always avoid if possible), you can use ``ListPlot[{list1,{#1,10#2}&@@@list2},Frame->True,
 FrameTicks->{
  {Automatic,
  Charting`FindTicks[10 MinMax[list2],MinMax[list2]]},
  {Automatic,Automatic}}]`` - adding whatever style elements you see fit.